# Counting the number of combinations

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, combinations

Let me start with the original question and answer:

Question:
Sometimes, Harvard, Yale and Princeton are referred to as the ‘Big 3’, and are often grouped together as schools because of their extensive similarities. If indeed these three schools were identical - that is, the ordering ‘Harvard Yale Princeton’ is taken as identical to the ordering ‘Yale Princeton Harvard’ - how many ways would there now be to rank the Ivies?

Answer:
$8!/3!$ because we are blocking out these 3 schools so we just divide.

My Question:
I understand the proposed logic, but this is how I chose to solve this question:
Since the 3 schools are considered identical, all that matters is the ordering of the other 5. Therefore the other 5 can be ordered in 5! ways. Now my block of 3 schools (which need to be together and it doesnt matter what order they are in) need to be added back. Essentially we are just adding 1 element in position 1 through 5 of the 5! ordered lists. For each list in 5!, we thus multiply by 6 because we can enter our university in one of 6 positions. So my answer was $5!\times 6$.

I believe the difference in solutions is because the original question is not mandating the univerities be adjacent to one another? But I wanted to verify if this was the descrepency.

Comment: It is traditional for combinatorics word problems to be confusingly or poorly worded, so that the hard part is guessing the mindset of the question-poser; that certainly is the case here.  Yes, you are right about the nature of the discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

In your solution, you are assuming that the Big $3$ are lumped together and you hence count the number of permutations of six entities: one *Big $3$* entity and five *non-Big $3$* entities. From what I can see, the problem asks for total arrangements, not assuming that the Big $3$ are all in one lump. Therefore your solution does not work.